# Restriction of a differential form vs pullback on submanifold $S^1\subset \Bbb R^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I was working through an exercise in Tu's book on differential geometry, (ex. 19.5) and I'm trying to get the most out of the exercise, and test my understanding, given that I've already computed the answer. I've starred $(*)$ where I'm stuck and collected them at the end for convenience.

It asks to compute the pullback of the form on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$ $$\omega=\frac{-y\,\mathrm{d}x+x\,\mathrm{d}y}{x^2+y^2}$$

by defining $c:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, as $c(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, and computing $c^*\omega$.

Doing the computation gives $c^*\omega=\mathrm{d}t$ which is a globally defined $1$-form on $\Bbb R$.

I'm trying to understand the outcome of mapping $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R^2$ as a circle of radius $1$ and it's relation to forms on the circle.

There's the obvious combination of $x^2+y^2$ which of course simplifies when calculating the pullback onto $\Bbb R$, so it makes a circle a clear choice, but suppose instead we take the same form $\omega$ and thought of $S^1\subset \Bbb R^2$ as a sub manifold and restricted the form, should one expect a similar (same) nice answer? $(*)$

I've seen two ways of doing this restriction:

$1)$ [Here pg.84](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~riviere/papers/SkriptDGI+DGII.pdf) it defines the restriction as the pullback of the inclusion of a sub manifold, so define $\omega\big|_{S^1}$ as $\iota^*\omega$ where $\iota:S^1\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$ as the unit circle say.

$2)$ In Tu's book however it says rather to consider $T_p S^1\subset T_p(\Bbb R^2-\{0\})$ and thus to consider for $X_1\in T_p S^1$ that $\left(\omega\big|_{S^1}\right)_p(X_1)=\omega_p(X_1)$.

So for $1)$ I could think of $S^1$ as being parametrised by an angle $t$ and take the inclusion as more or less the same as $c(t)$, which is why I would expect a similar answer, barring a possible point of discontinuity?? $(*)$

For $2)$ I can't see it working out as nicely because I've to try write a basis for the tangent space at $p\in S^1$ using the tangent space at $p\in \Bbb R^2$, so I could pick four open sets in $S^1$, like Tu does, $$U_x^+=\{(x,y)\in S^1\mid x>0\}\\
U_x^-=\{(x,y)\in S^1\mid x<0\}\\
U_y^+=\{(x,y)\in S^1\mid y>0\}\\
U_y^-=\{(x,y)\in S^1\mid y<0\}$$

A basis for the tangent space $T_p S^1$ for $p\in U_x^{\pm}$ is $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big|_p\}$, and for $T_p S^1$ with $p\in U_y^{\pm}$, it's $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big|_p\}$ so $$\omega\big|_{S^1} =\begin{cases}x\,\mathrm{d}y\quad  \text{ on } U_x \\ -y\,\mathrm{d}x \quad \text{ on } U_y \end{cases}$$

where $U_x=U_x^+\cup U_x^-$, and $U_y=U_y^+\cup U_y^-$, and setting $x^2+y^2=1$, since I should also restriction the function coefficients of the $1$-form to $S^1$ as well?? $(*)$

Or maybe more correctly $$\omega\big|_{S^1} =\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\quad  \text{ on } U_x \\ -\sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \quad \text{ on } U_y \end{cases}$$

Just to collect the $(*)$'s into a question:

1. When pulling back $\omega$ to $\Bbb R$ by mapping to $S^1$ we got a globally defined $1$-form, is the restriction of $\omega$ to $S^1$ by a pullback $\iota^*$ globally defined, call it $\mathrm{d}t$, or will there be a point of discontinuity, say if $S^1$ is included by the same map $c(t)$ with $t\in[0,2\pi]$, or for $t\in(0,2\pi)$, can it extend to the missing point?
2. Is the method of $2)$ correct? It seems to give a rather different $1$-form since it's now point dependent, and actually maybe it's not *well defined* on the intersection and that's why?

Comment: I actually think I know what I did wrong in $2)$, I think $xdy-ydx$ should become $x d(\sqrt(1-x^2))-\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ on $U_y$.

Comment: No, $\partial/\partial y$ is *not* a basis for $T_pS^1$ unless $p=(\pm1,0)$. A basis vector you can use, however, is $-y\,\partial/\partial x + x\,\partial/\partial y$.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for your reply. On $U_x^+$ say, I can project a point in $S^1$ onto the y-axis, which gives me a chart, if I consider the y-axis homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, say I call this chart $y$, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is a basis for $T_p S^1$ for $p\in U_x^+$. I think this might be my confusion though. I think if I want $S^1\subset \Bbb R^2$, I should align my choice of basis of $T_p S^1$ with the vector field you just mentioned $-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, which can be seen as a vector field on $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: As in to consider $T_p S^1 \subset T_p (R^2-\{0\})$, i should take the vector field $X(p)=-y(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big|_p+x(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big|_p$ for $p\in\Bbb R^2$, one of whose integral curves is $S^1$ and define the basis for $T_p S^1$ as $\{e_p\}$ where $e_p=y(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\big|_p+x(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\big|_p\in T_p(\Bbb R^2-\{0\})$, $\forall p\in S^1$.

Comment: When you have local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^k)$ on a submanifold $M\subset\Bbb R^n$, you do in fact write that $\partial/\partial x^1,\dots,\partial/\partial x^k$ give a basis for the tangent space. But what does this mean? In particular, if these are $k$ of your standard coordinates on $\Bbb R^n$, it certainly does not mean that the tangent space is everywhere the $x^1\dots x^k$-plane. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin That a good point, and I think it might clear things up a bit. I think I'm mixing up my charts? I was looking at the earlier chapter in Tu's book, and he talks about adapted charts, so ones whereby if $S\subset N$ and $(U,\phi)=(U,x^1\ldots x^n)$ is a chart containing $p\in S$, then on $U\cap S$, the chart looks like $(U\cap S,x^1,\ldots, x^k,0,\ldots,0)$ up to reordering of coordinates. The one I mentioned and called $y$ wasn't actually an adapted chart for $S^1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Is it the case that because $S^1\subset \Bbb R^2$ is given by $x^2+y^2=1$, in terms of the co-ordinates of $\Bbb R^2$, that $x\mathrm{d}x+y\mathrm{d}y=0$ for any $1$-form on $S^1$, so in particular $(x\mathrm{d}x+y\mathrm{d}y)(v)$ for any vector field should also be zero? In that case $v=\alpha(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\beta(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, gives $\alpha x+\beta y=0$, and hence I could choose $\alpha=-y$ and $\beta=x$? Replacing the words form and field above by co-vector and tangent vector when thinking of them at a point.

Comment: @TedShifrin Or equivalently that $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1\equiv 0$ when restricted to $S^1$ so for any tangent vector $Xf\equiv 0$ also, and arriving at the same idea. Apologies for taking up your time, but I'm happy for the help so far.

Comment: Yes, this latter stuff is all fine. Geometrically, we see that $x\,\partial/\partial x+y\,\partial/\partial y$ is normal to the circle, and this is precisely equivalent to the fact that $d(x^2+y^2)$ becomes $0$ when restricted (pulled back) to the circle.